# Get Connected device address bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I figured out we can get the connected bluetooth devices using BluetoothManager with the following code:

```
BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    List<BluetoothDevice> connected = manager.getConnectedDevices(GATT);
    Log.i("Connected Devices: ", connected.toString()+"");
```

However, I get "cannot resolve symbol 'GATT'". What should be done?

Update:

```
package in.justrobotics.jrbluetoothcontrol;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class TerminalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView connectedDevices;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_terminal);
        connectedDevices=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.connected_devices);
        BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        List<BluetoothDevice> connected = manager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothGatt.GATT);
//        if (connected.size()>=1) {
        Log.i("Connected Devices: ", connected.get(0).toString() + "");
        connectedDevices.setText(connected.get(0).toString());
//        }
    }

}
```

My app is crashing with this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.justrobotics.jrbluetoothcontrol/in.justrobotics.jrbluetoothcontrol.TerminalActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at in.justrobotics.jrbluetoothcontrol.TerminalActivity.onCreate(TerminalActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6875)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
    ... 9 more
```

Even though I have a speaker connected over BT.

Answer (score 1):

`import static android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile.GATT;`

Comment: Ok, no visible errors now. But connected.toString() returns null, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: connected is a list of several `BluetoothDevice` items and I guess you want to take an item out of it, `connected.get(position)` gives you the `BluetoothDevice` item at index `position`. You can follow developer guide [BluetoothDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice) because a `BluetoothDevice` class has a lot of information, which one you want

Comment: App is now crashing, though I have a speaker device connected. Adding the crash log and changed code to the question.

Comment: Seems the index is out of bounds :/

Answer (score 1):

I got into this yesterday and after giving a few try the following is somewhat working.

```
BluetoothManager myBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = myBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
Set s = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
Iterator it = s.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
            BluetoothDevice d = (BluetoothDevice) it.next();
            System.out.println("device is "+d.getName());
            }
```

Now the above only states which devices are bonded not necessarily connected. If I have only one headset bonded(paired) then.

```
int conState = mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
    System.out.println("connection state headset is "+conState);
```

If I have two same type of devices bonded, right now I do not have any idea, how to figure out which one is connected and which one is not.

Answer (score 0):

`connected.get(1)` will return the second connected device. You should be using `connected.get(0)`

Also add a check for `connected.size()` because otherwise it will crash if you have no connected devices.

Comment: Did that, still getting the error. connected.size() returns 0, why does that happen?

Comment: This happens when there are no devices unser `GATT` profile with `STATE_CONNECTED` try [getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html) for other states. Are you sure the device is connected?

Also make sure the app has bluetooth permission.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Will share a screenshot